# Flexbox layout css

Tags: html, css

I would like to fix the left sidebar and footer. someone help me?

I would like to keep this structure, therefore having only the "main" area with the scroll
it's possible using flex?

I enclose html and css code
the bar at the top I managed to fix it but could you common tell me if it is the correct method?

### HTML

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #edf0f1;
 
}

body {
 background-color: #24252a;
 margin: 0;
}

.logo {
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar {
 background-color: #1b1d22 !important;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #0088a9;
 background-color: #24252a;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 
}

.navbar a {
 padding: 14px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
 color: #0088a9;
 text-decoration: none;
}


.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.side {
 background-color: #1b1d22;
 flex: 20%;
 padding: 20px;
 border-right: 1px solid #0088a9;
}

.main {
  flex: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row, .navbar {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <aside class="side">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
        <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
        <h3>More Text</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
    </aside>
    <!-- The flexible grid (content) -->
 <div class="main">
        <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
        <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
        <p>Some text..</p>
        <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        <br>
        <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
        <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
        <p>Some text..</p>
        <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean that when you scroll the page,the left side won't scroll but be fixed,right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a sticky header and footer via flex, here is a minimal template to start from :

```css
/* layout*/
body {
margin:0;
height:100vh;/* would be wised to add a min-height to cover header + footer + a mimal height to see main */
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
main {
flex:1;
overflow:auto;
background:gray
}

/* demo */
main:hover:before {
content:'200vh of height';
display:block;
padding:0 0 200vh 0;
}
```

```html
<header>header of any height</header>
<main> scroll if needed</main>
<footer>footer of any height</footer>
```

possible example from your code :

```css
/* layout*/
body {
margin:0;
height:100vh;/* would be wised to add a min-height to cover header + footer + a mimal height to see main */
min-height:400px;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
main {
flex:1;
background:gray
}


/* ======= yours , with a couple fix =========== */
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #edf0f1;
 
}

body {
 background-color: #24252a;
 margin: 0;
}

.logo {
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar {
 background-color: #1b1d22 !important;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #0088a9;
 background-color: #24252a;
 width: 100%;
 
 
}

.navbar a {
 padding: 14px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
 color: #0088a9;
 text-decoration: none;
}


main {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-height:0;
}

.side {
 background-color: #1b1d22;
 flex: 20%;
 padding: 20px;
 border-right: 1px solid #0088a9;
  overflow:auto;
}

.main {
  flex: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
overflow:auto;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  main {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  aside {order:2}
}
@media screen and (max-height : 400px) {
body::before {content:'WARNING: Looks like a min-height is a good idea,  Please run me in FULL PAGE , then resize window to test behavior';
display:block;
color:crimson;
padding:1em;
text-align:center;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav class="navbar">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        </nav>
        </header>
<main><aside class="side">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
        <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
        <h3>More Text</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
    </aside>
    <!-- The flexible grid (content) -->
 <div class="main">
        <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
        <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
        <p>Some text..</p>
        <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        <br>
        <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
        <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
        <p>Some text..</p>
        <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
 </div></main>
<footer> <h2>Footer</h2></footer>
```